# Backbone.js and Fat-Free-Framework: moving data around

Tags: backbone.js, fat-free-framework

I'm comfortable with F3 but a total newb with backbone.js.  I'm trying to listen for some parameters in a get request and then have them available in a backbone view via a backbone template, and do it the "right" way....

So far here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

Url for the request:

```
http://myserver.com/route/?foo=12345
```

Here's my F3 route handling code:

```
F3::route('GET /route', 'start');
function start() {
    F3::set('foo', pg_escape_string($_REQUEST["foo"]) );
    echo Template::serve('page.html');
}
```

I set the `foo` F3 variable so I can use it in the page.html template.  Here's what page.html has in it:

```
<script>
var foo = '{{@foo}}';
</script>
```

So now I have the foo param as a global variable in javascript, and I want to get it into a backbone view, whose content is populated with a backbone template.

Here's what the backbone view has in it:

```
var fooView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#foo-container',
    template: _.template(templates.foo),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template( {foo:foo}  ));
    },
});
```

And here is what the backbone template has in it:

```
templates.foo = '\
Here is the value of foo in my template: <%= foo %>  \
';
```

Finally, lo and behold, the #foo-container div gets the data in it (after I execute `initialize` of course).

Question:  Is there a better way?  There has got to be a better way to do this, the data is going through two separate templating languages!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a better way. Backbone is designed for single-page applications that load the single HTML page from the server and then all subsequent data is loaded via AJAX with JSON response bodies. Model your server side request as a `Backbone.Model` with the correct URL. Bind your view rendering to the model's `change` event. Call `model.fetch()` on the model, which will make an AJAX `GET` request for you. Change your server side code to send JSON data instead of HTML with embedded JavaScript, then the model will receive and parse the JSON into javascript properties, fire a `change` event, which will cause the view to be rendered.